# Why Java doesn't support <<< operator

Tags: java, oop

Why doesn't Java support the `<<<` (unsigned left shift) operator, but does support the `>>>` (unsigned right shift) operator?

Comment: Left shifts are strange to say the least.

Comment: As yourself this question: What would such an operator do?

Comment: What's even the point of an unsigned left shift? Other languages like JavaScript doesn't support it either.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum correct. You don't have to worry about the sign of the number on a left shift

Comment: ARM assembly language (and probably others) have synonyms for arithmetics and logical shift left, ASL and LSL. (IIRC, it has been almost two decades.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Java adds the operator ">>>" to perform logical right shifts, but
>   because **the logical and arithmetic left-shift operations are
>   identical**, there is no "<<<" operator in Java.

from [Shifts in Java...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_Java)

Comment: why left shit operator is not supported in java please tell me with example if possible i am a beginner..

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum this answers both _why_ and _if_.

Comment: The reason why `>>>` exists is the lack of unsigned datatypes in Java.  In C/C++/C#, logical right shift is used when the left operand is unsigned, so you don't even see `>>>`.

Answer (score 8):

> Why doesn't Java support the `<<<` (unsigned left shift) operator, but does support the `>>>` (unsigned right shift) operator?

Because a (hypothetical) unsigned left shift operator would do exactly the same thing as the existing left shift operator.

(Hint: multiplying a binary integer by 2 entails left shifting by 1 and making the rightmost bit zero whether the integer representation is signed or unsigned.  Write some examples on a piece of paper and test it for yourself.)

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't Java support the <<< (unsigned left shift) operator, but
>   does support the >>> (unsigned right shift) operator?

That is because when you left shift the bits , the leftmost bit (AKA SIGNED Bit) is lost  anyways.

Since unsigned left shift operator would do exactly the same thing as the existing left shift operator, we don't have it.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a design mistake. The << is not arithmetic shift.
<< is supposed multiply 2
if you do

> 0xF0FFFFFF << 4

it return a positive number!
a negative number multiply 2 should never get a positive number.
the << is doing <<< work.

Comment: So what number *should* it return?  How do you represent `F0FFFFFF * 2^4` as a negative 64 bit signed value?  (What actually << is actually doing is multiplying by a power of 2 ... followed by standard Java `int` overflow behavior; i.e. truncation of the high bits.  It is not a mistake.)