# Why is there no unsigned left-shift operator in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
int a = -1;
System.out.println(a<<1);
```

This prints -2. That means the sign-bit is preserved. There is no unsigned left-shift operator in Java.  My question is, what if you want to push off the sign-bit, as when you are using an int not to store a value, but to contain a pattern of bits that represent something?

Comment: So you actually mean "why is there no **unsigned** left-shift operator"?

Comment: Try and think of an example where a logical left shift and arithmetic left shift would actually be different.

Comment: @Oliver, I am talking about a signed left-shift operator. Sorry, I edited the question a few minutes earlier

Comment: @khelwood, The example I have given above preserves the sign-bit. Let's say I don't want to.. in other words, in the code above, I want the result to be 2 and not -2.

Comment: It doesn't "preserve" the sign bit, it's just an artifact of the binary representation of -1.

Comment: @user3516726 That would not be a left shift. If you shift the bits left of -1 you get -2; that's why there's no `<<<` operator.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I meant "Why is there no unsigned left-shift operator in java".

Comment: Okay, all.. I should have thought of the 2's complement representation. @dasblinkenlight has made it clear. Thanks to all.

Comment: Really lame that these folks closed a perfectly clear and reasonable question.  Some tunnel vision here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Java doesn't support <<< oprerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318617/why-java-doesnt-support-oprerator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason this prints `-2` is not that the sign of `-1` gets preserved, but that the bit at position 31 which gets shifted into position 32 happens to be `1` as well. In other words, the sign after shifting left by one is determined by the value of the second highest bit.

Binary representation of `-1` has `1`s in all bits ([an explanation can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)), so the result remains negative as you continue shifting the number, until you shift out the last `1` bit after 32 shifts.

If you would like to drop the sign, you can mask the result to make it positive.

> Why is there no unsigned left-shift operator in Java

Unlike shifting right, when the shift operator needs to make a decision on what to shift into the vacated position of the most significant bit, the value being shifted left determines the value of the new sign bit. The new zero bit is shifted into the least significant position, which does not have any special meaning.

Comment: Let him know why, too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Thanks, @dasblinkenlight, I should have remembered the 2's complement representation. I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: "until you shift out the last 1 bit after 32 shifts." In the case of `-1` only [31 shifts are possible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19), so the result of `-1 << x` will always be negative (or error, for x > Integer.MAX_VALUE or x < Integer.MIN_VALUE).

Comment: Actually if you look at it this way: `>>>` can change the sign, `>>` can't change the sign, `<<` can change the sign, then it seems that one is missing.  I mean if there is one operation that keeps the sign bit untouched when shifting right, why there is no operation that keeps the sign bit untouched when shifting left.